# Limit of double integral in polar

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I solve this limit? The only hint for this question was to use a fundamental theorem of calculus[limit](https://gyazo.com/c531af72af6481038db31c4e99914d27)

What I tried to do was first convert to polar, since the limit is in terms of r. However, after converting to polar I am unsure of what to do. Am I allowed to use LHopital’s rule if the function inside the integral goes to 0/0?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please provide your understanding and attempt to solve the question. This will not attract downvotes to your question and will prevent it from being closed. For more information on how to ask a good question, you may refer: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes by polar coordinates we obtain

$$\frac 3{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r \frac{f(\rho)}{r^2}\,d\rho \,d\theta =3\frac{\int_0^r f(\rho)\,d\rho}{r^2}$$

and then we can usel'Hoptal.